# Does cycles use the light portal power value?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

When marking an area light as a portal, some controls get disabled. However blender still lets me change the power and color of the light portal. Changing them doesn't seem to affect my scene, but I'm not sure if it's truly ignored, or does the power of the light portal is used for probability calculations within the renderer.

Should the light portal power be set to the estimated light coming through the portal or is it ignored?